# How to do popup input form that will not reset the page after saving?

Tags: html, jquery

I have a function that will click the button then the input form will popup and the card will show. But after clicking the button, the card will along with the popup form then when I am saving the form, the card is removed.

Before I click the button:

[image]

After I clicked the button:

[image]

When I clicked save button:

[image]

```js
$(function(){
      $('button').on('click', function() {
        $('.popup').css({display:'flex'})

        $('<div class="card"><h1>Budget</h1><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">Month 1</a></h5><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add Daliy Expenses</a></div></div>').insertBefore('.card:last');
      })
    })
```

```css
.popup {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.popup-content {
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

.sub {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #34495e;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 29px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    margin-top: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

input {
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid gray; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-box-tabs"></div>
        <div class="tab-panels">
      <div id="panel1" class="panel active">
        <div class="flex-box-panel">
          <div class="flex-box-card">
            <div class="card">
              <h1>Budget</h1>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">Month 1</a></h5>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add Daliy Expenses</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <div class="pos">
                <button class="round-button">&#43;</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

  <div class="popup">
    <div class="popup-content">
      <form method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Budget">
        <input type="submit" name="Save" value="submit" class="sub">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Is there some way or functions to popup first the form and will show the card after saving it?

Comment: Investigate ajax form submission. What are you using to process the from?

Comment: Can you add the CSS please?

Comment: @AezignSpace, done

Comment: @JonP, so ajax will do? I will study now ajax hoping to resolve my issue. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add this line [event.preventDefault();](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) and recieve event from function.

```
$(function(){
      $('button').on('click', function(event) { <--- here
         event.preventDefault();  <--- here
        $('.popup').css({display:'flex'})

        $('<div class="card"><h1>Budget</h1><div class="card-body"><h5 class="card-title"><a href="#">Month 1</a></h5><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add Daliy Expenses</a></div></div>').insertBefore('.card:last');
      })
    })
```

Comment: Note that this will prevent the form from submitting/saving

Comment: Instead, you can do an AJAX request, probably a POST, if you need to send the data somewhere without reloading the page. e.g. save to a database.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a form submit, you can simply use AJAX to do operations without reloading the page...